# Numerically solving an eigenvalue problem: Are forward/backwards difference schemes inappropriate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, computational-physics

Say I want to solve the eigenvalue problem $$\mathbf{p} \mathrm{u} = p \mathrm{u}$$ where $\mathbf{p}$ is a matrix representation of the momentum operator, $p$ are the eigenvalues and $\mathrm{u}$ the eigenvectors. When I use a central difference scheme to discretize $\mathbf{p}$ I get the Hermitian matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0   & z & \cdots &  \\\\
z^\star & 0 & z     & \cdots  \\\\
\cdots & z^\star & 0 & z & \cdots \\\\
& & & \ddots \\\\
& &\cdots & z^\star& 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$
However, if I use a forward difference scheme, I would get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
z^\star   & z & \cdots &  \\\\
0 & z^\star & z     & \cdots  \\\\
\cdots & 0 & z^\star & z & \cdots \\\\
& & & \ddots \\\\
& &  \cdots & 0& z^\star 
\end{bmatrix}$$ which isn't Hermitian. Does this mean the forward difference scheme is not appropriate for these kinds of eigenvalue problems?

Comment: Is there anything you'd want an answer to say except "Yes"?

Comment: If the answer is yes, then I think that settles it though it is surprising to me that there is such sensitivity to how the derivative is approximated

Comment: Actually, I noticed my title question was not the same as the question posed in the text so I have updated it

Comment: Why is it surprising that difference schemes are almost universally poor approximations? That's one of the key takeaways of introductory level numerical techniques classes. It is almost always better to find an integral approximation to the problem.